# What do the special options in the Census menu do?

Tags: kittens-game

In recent updates, there have been big changes in the Census menu. Ex:  Kittens now have titles, often related to their job (Scholars can become Scientists, for example) and can be promoted in those titles at a cost of experience; kittens can also be made Leaders or Senators.  What do these options do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature has been implemented for a while now, though a slightly less complex version of it. There are no longer Senators, only a single position called Leader that you can assign.

Any kitten can also have one "trait", which doesn't need to be related to their profession. Each trait grants a bonus to some aspect of the game. The bonus applies for whichever trait your Leader has.

The list of traits can be seen in [the source code](https://bitbucket.org/bloodrizer/kitten-game/src/3bce6f560e9b869bdc6f97a4e49de16001c80f86/js/village.js?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) for the game, but as of right now (v1.2.0.0) the traits do the following things:

- Manager - boost to hunting (`huntRatio += 0.5`)
- Scientist - discount on science needed for buildings (`cost *= 0.99`)
- Engineer - boost to crafting (`craftRatio += 0.05` )
- Merchant - boost to trading (`tradeRatio += 0.03` )
- Philosopher - discount on religious upgrades (`cost *= 0.99`)

The other two (metallurgist and chemist) don't do anything yet.

In addition, the kitten assigned as Leader will get a bonus to whatever job they are doing based on their rank (I don't believe rank has any impact on kittens other than the leader.)

Answer (score 6):

They have no effect as of now, and were in fact explicitly called out in the [full changelog](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/changelog.txt) as a work in progress when introduced.

Comment: Update ? A leader has a production bonus now afaik.