# What is the purpose of senators and leader?

Tags: kittens-game

Also what do I do when promoting them with experience ? Do they get more efficient ?

Comment: Something has changed since then. We can now upgrade those kitties. I checked the source code, but I cannot find anything that is useful (ingame). So it looks like it is still work in progress, and upgrading the little devils does not do anything at the moment. This hopefully will change, and then this question is indeed exactly the same as my question.

Comment: Agreed, duplicate of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186138/whats-up-with-the-leaders-and-councils).  @Mathias711 I suggested an edit to the original question to make it stand the test of time better.